# javascript Bracket notation syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

Is there a better way to write that :

```
var modifier = {};
modifier[rowId + '.' + columnName] = value;
```

I can't use the following as it only accepts a constant for the first part.

```
modifier = { rowId + '.' + columnName : value}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is the only way.

Comment: I'm just gratefull for the former. It's neat in contrast to other languages.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol There's always evil `eval` :)

Comment: `eval("modifer = { " + rowId + '.' + columnName + " : value}")`

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't like neither the eval syntax but so will keep the above syntax.

Comment: I think ECMAScript 6 should be getting expressions for object initializer keys.

Comment: Yep, looks like it is in the current spec draft. You'll be able to do `var modifier = {[rowId + '.' + columnName] : value}`